# Dust JS Dot Into string Key Name

Tags: javascript, templates, dust.js

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but I have "dates" as a key for the object and Dust seems to just output exactly what I put in rather than evaluate properly.

```
 {#.weeks pos=items}
    {pos['2016-02-15].id}
 {/.weeks}
```

Output:

{pos.'2016-02-15'.id}

How can I output the ID rather than output the string?

Comment: Can you clarify what your data looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Dust does not allow the character `-` as part of an array key.

As you mentioned in your comment, `-` is allowed in Dust references, but the rules are slightly different.

Dust references must not start with a number, and contain the characters `0-9a-zA-Z_$-`. This mirrors the rules for real Javascript variables, except for the hyphen.

Array keys are allowed to start with numbers, but cannot contain hyphens. So when you use a date as part of the key, Dust uses the array key evaluation path since the date starts with a number.

This would work, for example, using the array-key evaluation path:

```
{#.weeks pos=items}
  {pos[20160215].id}
{/.weeks}
```

And so would this, because it uses the reference evaluation path:

```
{#.weeks pos=items}
  {pos[date-2016-02-15].id}
{/.weeks}
```

You'll have to munge your data slightly.

I think you've uncovered an inconsistency in the way Dust handles reference naming. In early Dust, references were only allowed to be valid JS variable names. This restriction was relaxed later on but there are clearly some rough bits around it.

Comment: Is there no way to escape or avoid munging data?

Comment: You could write a custom helper that extracts keys in this format.

Comment: I read this though in the dust template. A Dust key is one or more of the following characters: a-z, A-Z, _ (underscore), $, 0-9, or -

Comment: Sorry I should have elaborated more. I have updated my answer.